# MYSQL--> Error Code: 1140

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Necesito ayuda con este error que me marca mysql y no entiendo que significa, y como tendría que resolverlo.

```
drop temporary table if exists MinP;  
create temporary table MinP
(select CantidadPS.cuil, min(CantidadPS.CantPrendas)
from
(select ps.cuil, count(*) as CantPrendas
from prendas_sastres ps 
inner join prendas p on p.nro_persona=ps.nro_persona 
and p.cod_tipo_prenda=ps.cod_tipo_prenda and p.nro_pedido=ps.nro_pedido
where fecha_fin_real is null and fecha_medicion is not null
group by ps.cuil)CantidadPS);
```

El Error que me marca es el siguiente:

```
Error Code: 1140. In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 
of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'CantidadPS.cuil'; 
this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: En la última linea de tu código Sql, tienes dos parentesis que cierran. El primero deberia ser para abrir y el segundo para cerrar. ¿Podria ser este el error?

Answer (score -1):

Intenta haciendolo de la siguiente forma:

```
drop temporary table if exists MinP;  
create temporary table MinP
(select CantidadPS.cuil, min(CantidadPS.CantPrendas)
from (select ps.cuil, count(*) as CantPrendas
    from prendas_sastres ps 
    inner join prendas p 
        on p.nro_persona=ps.nro_persona 
        on p.cod_tipo_prenda=ps.cod_tipo_prenda 
        on p.nro_pedido=ps.nro_pedido
    where fecha_fin_real is null 
        and fecha_medicion is not null
    group by ps.cuil) as CantidadPS)
group by CantidadPS.cuil;
```

Saludos.